# Trying to install JDK

Tags: jdk, update-alternatives

I'm trying to install JDK on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I downloaded it from oracle website. Than I extracted it and moved in `usr/lib/java`.
It says java doesn't exist but it does.

[image: screenshot]

I use this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZB3Iy7Lve4

Comment: I recommend just installing OpenJDK instead. It's available directly from the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

To install Openjdk 6:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-6*
```

To install Openjdk 7:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-7*
```

**NOTE**: If you already have the downloaded `.tar.gz` file, something similar to this - `jdk-8u66-linux-x64.tar.gz` then before proceeding any further copy it to `/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer`. Create the necessary folders if required (**root may be necessary**) and also change `8` in `/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer` with the correct version.

To install Oracle Java 7:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

To install Oracle Java 8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To install Oracle Java 9 (**not recommended**):

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```